# arm-none-eabi libgcc Missing Functions

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arm

So am running into an issue here with compiling bare_metal Armv7.

When i compile i am getting the error below.

```
obj/main/TestF7/graph/graph.o: In function `entry':
__compute_module:(.text+0xafe): undefined reference to `__multi3'
__compute_module:(.text+0xcfa): undefined reference to `__multi3'
__compute_module:(.text+0xe90): undefined reference to `__multi3'
__compute_module:(.text+0x1000): undefined reference to `__multi3'
```

The compile parameters I am using.

```
 -lm -nostartfiles --specs=nosys.specs -lc -lnosys -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion   -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ffast-math -Ofast  -static -Wl,-gc-sections
```

When I run

```
nm /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.3.1/libgcc.a
```

I dont see the multi3 Function however when I run the below command I can see the function there.

```
nm /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.5.0/libgcc.a
```

How can I fix this issue I have been at it for 10 days now and I'm losing my mind.

Here is the command

```
    echo "%% C++ graph_interface.cc" "" &&  ./tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -c -o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/graph/graph_interface.o -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion    -I./src/main -I./src/main/target -I./lib/main/STM32F7/Drivers/STM32F7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I./lib/main/STM32F7/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Inc -I./lib/main/STM32F7/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/CDC/Inc -I./lib/main/STM32F7/Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I./lib/main/STM32F7/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F7xx/Include -I./src/main/vcp_hal -I./lib/main/FatFS -I./lib/main/MAVLink -I./src/main/target/KAKUTEF7 -I./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Include -I/home/dronemesh/tensorflow/bazel-tensorflow/external/eigen_archive -I/home/dronemesh/tensorflow -I/home/dronemesh/nn/ComputeLibrary/build -I./gen/src  -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wdouble-promotion -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -pedantic -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DUSE_FULL_LL_DRIVER -DSTM32F745xx -DHSE_VALUE=8000000 -DARM_MATH_MATRIX_CHECK -DARM_MATH_ROUNDING -D__FPU_PRESENT=1 -DUNALIGNED_SUPPORT_DISABLE -DARM_MATH_CM7 -DFLASH_SIZE=2048 -DHSE_VALUE=8000000 -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -DKAKUTEF7 -DKAKUTEF7 -D'__FORKNAME__="neuroflight"' -D'__TARGET__="KAKUTEF7"' -D'__REVISION__="7fbbf0d7b"' -save-temps=obj -MMD -MP  -D'__ANDROID__' -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ffast-math -O2 src/main/graph/graph_interface.cc
%% C++ graph_interface.cc 
Linking KAKUTEF7 
./tools/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -o obj/main/neuroflight_KAKUTEF7.elf obj/main/KAKUTEF7/startup_stm32f745xx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/target/system_stm32f7xx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/accgyro/accgyro_mpu.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/adc_stm32f7xx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_i2c_hal.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/dma_stm32f7xx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/light_ws2811strip_hal.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_spi_ll.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/pwm_output_dshot_hal.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/timer_hal.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/timer_stm32f7xx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/system_stm32f7xx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/serial_uart_stm32f7xx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/serial_uart_hal.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/accgyro/accgyro_spi_icm20689.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/barometer/barometer_bmp280.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/compass/compass_hmc5883l.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/light_ws2811strip.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/max7456.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/BasicMathFunctions/arm_mult_f32.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_rfft_fast_f32.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_cfft_f32.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_rfft_fast_init_f32.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_cfft_radix8_f32.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/CommonTables/arm_common_tables.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/ComplexMathFunctions/arm_cmplx_mag_f32.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/StatisticsFunctions/arm_max_f32.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/./lib/main/DSP_Lib/Source/TransformFunctions/arm_bitreversal2.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/build/build_config.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/build/debug.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/build/version.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/target.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/main.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/bitarray.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/crc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/encoding.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/filter.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/huffman.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/huffman_table.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/maths.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/printf.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/streambuf.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/string_light.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/time.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/typeconversion.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/config/config_eeprom.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/config/feature.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/config/config_streamer.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/adc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/buf_writer.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_i2c_config.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_i2c_busdev.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_i2c_soft.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_spi.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_spi_config.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_spi_pinconfig.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/bus_spi_soft.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/buttons.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/display.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/exti.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/io.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/light_led.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/pinio.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/resource.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/rcc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/serial.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/serial_pinconfig.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/serial_uart_pinconfig.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/sound_beeper.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/stack_check.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/system.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/transponder_ir.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/transponder_ir_arcitimer.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/transponder_ir_ilap.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/transponder_ir_erlt.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/config.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/fc_dispatch.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/fc_hardfaults.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/fc_tasks.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/runtime_config.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/interface/msp.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/interface/msp_box.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/beeper.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/piniobox.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/serial.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/statusindicator.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/transponder_ir.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/msp/msp_serial.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/adc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/beeper.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/beeper_dev.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/bus_i2c.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/bus_spi.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/dashboard.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/max7456.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/pinio.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/piniobox.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/pg.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/rx_pwm.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/sdcard.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/pg/vcd.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/scheduler/scheduler.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/adcinternal.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/battery.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/current.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/voltage.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/fc_init.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/controlrate_profile.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/camera_control.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/accgyro/gyro_sync.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/pwm_esc_detect.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/pwm_output.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/rx/rx_spi.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/rx/rx_xn297.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/rx/rx_pwm.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/serial_softserial.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/fc_core.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/fc_rc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/rc_adjustments.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/rc_controls.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/fc/rc_modes.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/altitude.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/failsafe.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/imu.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/mixer.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/mixer_tricopter.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/pid.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/graph/neuro.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/servos.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/servos_tricopter.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/interface/cli.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/interface/settings.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/serial_4way.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/serial_4way_avrootloader.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/serial_4way_stk500v2.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/ibus.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/jetiexbus.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/msp.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/pwm.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/rx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/rx_spi.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/crsf.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/sbus.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/sbus_channels.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/spektrum.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/spektrum_vtx_control.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/spektrum_rssi.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/sumd.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/sumh.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/xbus.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/rx/fport.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/acceleration.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/boardalignment.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/compass.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/gyro.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/gyroanalyse.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/initialisation.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/blackbox/blackbox.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/blackbox/blackbox_encoding.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/blackbox/blackbox_io.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_blackbox.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_builtin.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_imu.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_ledstrip.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_misc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_osd.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_power.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_vtx_rtc6705.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_vtx_smartaudio.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/cms/cms_menu_vtx_tramp.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/colorconversion.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/common/gps_conversion.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/display_ug2864hsweg01.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/rangefinder/rangefinder_hcsr04.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/rangefinder/rangefinder_lidartf.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/serial_escserial.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/vtx_common.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/flight/navigation.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/dashboard.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/displayport_max7456.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/displayport_msp.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/displayport_oled.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/displayport_rcdevice.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/displayport_srxl.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/rcdevice_cam.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/rcdevice.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/rcdevice_osd.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/gps.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/ledstrip.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/osd.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/barometer.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/rangefinder.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/telemetry.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/crsf.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/srxl.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/frsky_hub.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/hott.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/jetiexbus.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/smartport.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/ltm.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/mavlink.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/msp_shared.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/ibus.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/telemetry/ibus_shared.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/sensors/esc_sensor.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/vtx_string.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/vtx.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/vtx_rtc6705.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/vtx_smartaudio.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/vtx_tramp.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/vtx_control.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_ll_rcc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_adc_ex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_tim.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_dma.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_pwr.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_uart.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_flash.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_i2c.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_dma_ex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_rcc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_ll_dma2d.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_rcc_ex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_ll_spi.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_pwr_ex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_ll_gpio.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_usart.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_pcd.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_ll_usb.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_flash_ex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_spi.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_ll_dma.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_i2c_ex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_ll_tim.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_adc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_gpio.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_pcd_ex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_ll_utils.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_cortex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/stm32f7xx_hal_tim_ex.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/usbd_core.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/usbd_ctlreq.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/usbd_ioreq.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/usbd_cdc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/sdcard.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/sdcard_standard.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/asyncfatfs/asyncfatfs.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/io/asyncfatfs/fat_standard.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/vcp_hal/usbd_desc.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/vcp_hal/usbd_conf.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/vcp_hal/usbd_cdc_interface.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/serial_usb_vcp.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/drivers/usb_io.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/graph/graph.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/graph/graph_interface.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/xla_compiled_cpu_function.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/tensorflow/compiler/aot/runtime.o obj/main/KAKUTEF7/tensorflow/compiler/xla/executable_run_options.o -lm -nostartfiles --specs=nano.specs -lc -lnosys -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion   -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -ffast-math -Ofast  -static -Wl,-gc-sections,-Map,./obj/main/neuroflight_KAKUTEF7.map -Wl,-L./src/main/target/link -Wl,--cref -Wl,--no-wchar-size-warning -T./src/main/target/link/stm32_flash_f745.ld
obj/main/KAKUTEF7/graph/graph.o: In function `entry':
__compute_module:(.text+0xda6): undefined reference to `__multi3'
__compute_module:(.text+0xfa2): undefined reference to `__multi3'
__compute_module:(.text+0x1138): undefined reference to `__multi3'
__compute_module:(.text+0x12a8): undefined reference to `__multi3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:292: recipe for target 'obj/main/neuroflight_KAKUTEF7.elf' failed
make[1]: *** [obj/main/neuroflight_KAKUTEF7.elf] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dronemesh/neuroflight'
Makefile:415: recipe for target 'hex' failed
make: *** [hex] Error 2
```

Comment: please post a complete example, should really only need a few lines of code to trigger this.  do you need the multiply.  grab the code for it and make it part of your project, etc...basically the linker is not being told (by the compiler) where to look (gnus linker doesnt know where anything is it has to be told)

Comment: please provide the complete command lines not partial. as part of your example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @old_timer Its noa simple command its a large project I can set the build to verbose and post the whole output here if that would help.

Comment: @old_timer I have edited the post with the command now

Comment: the multiply comes from a single operation  a = b*c; somewhere in the code, should be trivial to see that between the source and the compiled output and then use that as a one line example program.

Comment: how are you even generating ti mode code for a 32 bit arm? are you linking in someone elses library?

Comment: So there is some sort of a bug in the tensorflow compile that when it generates the C code it adds multi3 which is a 64bit lib. the LLVM cross compiler is doing this automatically and i cant find a way around it.